# Implode Multiple values from Select2 form and Insert to database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I am using multiple select from a select2 dropdown and I want to store all the multiple values selected from the form in

**database "xyz"**

**tablename='pp_companies'**

**row="category1"** <-- Need this row to be an array , which has the selected values in CSV format)

**View** file

```
<div class="titlehead">Courses Offered</div>
    <div class="input-group <?php echo (form_error('category1'))?'has-error':'';?>">
    <label class="input-group-addon">Category </label>
    <select name="category1" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="Engineering" <?php echo (set_value('category1')=='Engineering')?'selected':''; ?>>Engineering</option>
      <option value="Management" <?php echo (set_value('category1')=='Management')?'selected':''; ?>>Management</option>
      <option value="Law" <?php echo (set_value('category1')=='Law')?'selected':''; ?>>Law</option>
    </select>
```

Once i submit the form , It sends only the last data selected from the input, which is "Law" in this case

My **Controller**

```
    public function index()
{
    $data['ads_row'] = $this->ads;
    $data['title'] = 'Create New Employer Account at '.SITE_URL;
    $data['msg']='';
    $data['result_cities'] = $this->cities_model->get_all_cities();
    $data['result_countries'] = $this->countries_model->get_all_countries();
    $data['result_industries'] = $this->industries_model->get_all_industries();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[pp_employers.email]|strip_all_tags');  
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_pass', 'Confirm password', 'trim|required|matches[pass]|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', 'Your name', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_city', 'City', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile_phone', 'Mobile', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_name', 'Company name', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('industry_id', 'Industry', 'trim|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_location', 'Company address', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_description', 'Company Description', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags|secure');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_join', 'Company Join', 'trim|strip_all_tags|secure');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_phone', 'Company Phone', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');        
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_of_employees', 'No of Employees', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_website', 'Company Website', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');        
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category1', 'Category1', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');    
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Verification code', 'trim|required|validate_ml_spam');

    if (empty($_FILES['company_logo']['name']))
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_logo', 'Company Logo', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="errowbox"><div class="erormsg">', '</div></div>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data['cpt_code'] = create_ml_captcha();

        $this->load->view('employer_signup_view',$data);
        return;

    }

    $current_date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $company_slug = make_slug($this->input->post('company_name'));
    $is_slug = $this->companies_model->check_slug($company_slug);
    if($is_slug>0){
        $company_slug.='-'.time();
    }
    $employer_array = array(
                            'first_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
                            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                            'pass_code' => $this->input->post('pass'),
                            'mobile_phone' => $this->input->post('mobile_phone'),
                            'home_phone' => $this->input->post('home_phone'),
                            'country' => $this->input->post('country'),
                            'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                            'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address(),
                            'dated' => $current_date_time
    );


    $company_array = array(
                            'company_name' => $this->input->post('company_name'),
                            'industry_ID' => $this->input->post('industry_id'),
                            'company_phone' => $this->input->post('company_phone'),
                            'company_location' => $this->input->post('company_location'),
                            'company_city' => $this->input->post('company_city'),
                            'company_website' => $this->input->post('company_website'),
                            'no_of_employees' => $this->input->post('no_of_employees'),                             
                            'category1'=> $this->input->post('category1'),                              
                            'company_description' => $this->input->post('company_description'),
                            'company_join' => $this->input->post('company_join'),
                            'company_slug' => $company_slug,
                            'ownership_type' => $this->input->post('ownership_type')
    );
    if (!empty($_FILES['company_logo']['name'])){


        $company_name_for_file = strtolower($this->input->post('company_name'));
        $real_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../public/uploads/employer/');
        $config['upload_path'] = $real_path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['overwrite'] = true;
        $config['max_size'] = 6000;
        $config['file_name'] = 'JOBPORTAL-'.time();
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('company_logo')){
            /*if($obj_row->company_logo){
                @unlink($real_path.'/'.$obj_row->company_logo); 
                @unlink($real_path.'/thumb/'.$obj_row->company_logo);
            }*/
        }

        $image = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
        $image_name = $image['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $company_array['company_logo']=$image_name;
        $thumb_config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $thumb_config['source_image']   = $real_path.'/'.$image_name;
        $thumb_config['new_image']  = $real_path.'/thumb/'.$image_name;
        $thumb_config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $thumb_config['height'] = 50;
        $thumb_config['width']   = 70;

        $this->image_lib->initialize($thumb_config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
    }
    $company_id = $this->companies_model->add_company($company_array);
    $employer_array['company_ID'] = $company_id;
    $employer_id = $this->employers_model->add_employer($employer_array);

    $user_data = array(
            'user_id' => $employer_id,
             'user_email' => $this->input->post('email'),
             'first_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
             'slug' => $company_slug,
             'last_name' => '',
             'is_user_login' => TRUE,
             'is_job_seeker' => FALSE,
             'is_employer' => TRUE
             );
    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

    //Sending email to the user
    $row_email = $this->email_model->get_records_by_id(3);
    $config = array();
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->clear(TRUE);
    $this->email->from($row_email->from_email, $row_email->from_name);
    $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
    $this->email->subject($row_email->subject);
    $mail_message = $this->email_drafts_model->employer_signup($row_email->content, $employer_array);
    $this->email->message($mail_message);
    $this->email->send();

    redirect(base_url('employer/post_new_job'),'');
}
```

**Model**

```
public function add_company($data){

        $return = $this->db->insert('pp_companies', $data);
        if ((bool) $return === TRUE) {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        } else {
            return $return;
        }       

}   

public function update_company($id, $data){
    $this->db->where('ID', $id);
    $return=$this->db->update('pp_companies', $data);
    return $return;
}

public function delete_company($id){
    $this->db->where('ID', $id);
    $this->db->delete('pp_companies');
    return true;
}



/*public function get_all_companies($per_page, $page) {
    $this->db->select('pp_companies.*');
    $this->db->from('pp_companies');
    $this->db->order_by("pp_companies.ID", "DESC"); 
    $this->db->limit($per_page, $page);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->result();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}*/

public function get_all_companies($per_page, $page) {
    $this->db->select('pp_employers.ID, pp_employers.dated, pp_employers.email, pp_employers.first_name, pp_employers.last_name, pp_employers.company_ID, pp_employers.sts, pp_companies.ID AS CID, pp_companies.company_name, pp_companies.company_phone, pp_companies.company_website, pp_companies.industry_ID, pp_companies.company_logo');
    $this->db->from('pp_companies');
    $this->db->join('pp_employers', 'pp_employers.company_ID = pp_companies.ID', 'inner');
    $this->db->order_by("pp_employers.ID", "DESC"); 
    $this->db->limit($per_page, $page);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->result();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}

public function record_count($table_name) {
    return $this->db->count_all($table_name);
}

public function get_company_by_id($id) {
    $this->db->select('pp_companies.*');
    $this->db->from('pp_companies');
    $this->db->where('pp_companies.ID', $id);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}

public function check_slug($slug) {

    $this->db->where('company_slug', $slug);
    $this->db->from('pp_companies');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}

public function check_slug_edit($CID, $slug) {

    $this->db->where('company_slug', $slug);
    $this->db->where('ID !=', $CID);
    $this->db->from('pp_companies');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}



public function get_company_by_old_id($id) {
    $this->db->select('pp_companies.*');
    $this->db->from('pp_companies');
    $this->db->where('pp_companies.old_company_id', $id);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}
```

**2nd Model**

```
public function add_employer($data){

        $return = $this->db->insert('pp_employers', $data);
        if ((bool) $return === TRUE) {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        } else {
            return $return;
        }       

}   

public function update_employer($id, $data){
    $this->db->where('ID', $id);
    $return=$this->db->update('pp_employers', $data);
    return $return;
}

public function update($id, $data){
    $this->db->where('ID', $id);
    $return=$this->db->update('pp_employers', $data);
    return $return;
}

public function delete_employer($id){
    $this->db->where('ID', $id);
    $this->db->delete('pp_employers');
}

public function authenticate_employer($user_name, $password) {
    $this->db->select('pp_employers.*, pp_companies.company_slug');
    $this->db->from('pp_employers');
    $this->db->join('pp_companies', 'pp_employers.company_ID = pp_companies.ID', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('email', $user_name);
    $this->db->where('pass_code', $password);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}

public function authenticate_employer_by_email($user_name) {
    $this->db->select('pp_employers.*');
    $this->db->from('pp_employers');
    $this->db->where('email', $user_name);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}

public function authenticate_employer_by_password($ID, $password) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('pp_employers');
    $this->db->where('ID', $ID);
    $this->db->where('pass_code', $password);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}

public function is_email_already_exists($ID, $email) {
    $this->db->select('ID');
    $this->db->from('pp_employers');
    $this->db->where('ID !=', $ID);
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row('ID');
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}


public function get_all_employers($per_page, $page) {
    $this->db->select('pp_employers.ID, pp_employers.dated, pp_employers.email, pp_employers.first_name, pp_employers.last_name, pp_employers.company_ID, pp_employers.sts, pp_employers.city, pp_employers.country, pp_employers.top_employer, pp_employers.ip_address, pp_companies.ID AS CID, pp_companies.company_name, pp_companies.company_logo, pp_companies.company_phone, pp_companies.company_location, pp_companies.company_slug');
    $this->db->from('pp_employers');
    $this->db->join('pp_companies', 'pp_employers.company_ID = pp_companies.ID', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by("pp_employers.ID", "DESC"); 
    $this->db->limit($per_page, $page);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->result();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}

public function record_count($table_name) {
    return $this->db->count_all($table_name);
}

public function get_employer_by_id($id) {
    $this->db->select('pp_employers.*, pp_companies.ID AS CID,pp_companies.company_name,pp_companies.company_email,pp_companies.ownership_type,pp_companies.company_ceo,pp_companies.industry_ID,pp_companies.ownership_type,pp_companies.company_description,pp_companies.company_location,pp_companies.no_of_offices,pp_companies.company_website,pp_companies.no_of_employees, pp_companies.established_in, pp_companies.company_logo, pp_companies.company_folder, pp_companies.company_type, pp_companies.company_fax, pp_companies.company_slug, pp_companies.company_phone, pp_job_industries.industry_name');
    $this->db->from('pp_employers');
    $this->db->join('pp_companies', 'pp_employers.company_ID = pp_companies.ID', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('pp_job_industries', 'pp_companies.industry_ID = pp_job_industries.ID', 'left');
    $this->db->where('pp_employers.ID', $id);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}

public function get_employer_by_id_simple($id) {
    $this->db->select('pp_employers.*');
    $this->db->from('pp_employers');
    $this->db->where('pp_employers.ID', $id);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}

public function get_employer_by_company_id($cid) {
    $this->db->select('pp_employers.*, pp_companies.ID AS CID,pp_companies.company_name,pp_companies.company_email,pp_companies.company_ceo,pp_companies.industry_ID,pp_companies.ownership_type,pp_companies.company_description,pp_companies.company_location,pp_companies.no_of_offices,pp_companies.company_website,pp_companies.no_of_employees, pp_companies.established_in, pp_companies.company_logo, pp_companies.company_folder, pp_companies.company_type, pp_companies.company_fax, pp_companies.company_phone');
    $this->db->from('pp_employers');
    $this->db->join('pp_companies', 'pp_employers.company_ID = pp_companies.ID', 'left');
    $this->db->where('pp_employers.company_ID', $cid);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}

public function search_all_employers($per_page, $page, $search_parameters, $wild_card='') {

    $where = ($wild_card=='yes')?'where':'like';
    $this->db->select('pp_employers.ID, pp_employers.dated, pp_employers.email, pp_employers.first_name, pp_employers.last_name, pp_employers.company_ID, pp_employers.sts, pp_employers.top_employer, pp_companies.ID AS CID, pp_companies.company_name, pp_companies.company_logo');
    $this->db->from('pp_employers');
    $this->db->join('pp_companies', 'pp_employers.company_ID = pp_companies.ID', 'inner');
    $this->db->$where($search_parameters);
    $this->db->order_by("pp_employers.ID", "DESC"); 
    $this->db->limit($per_page, $page);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->result();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    //echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
    return $return;
}

public function search_record_count($table_name, $search_parameters) {
    //return $this->db->count_all($table_name);
    $this->db->like($search_parameters);
    $this->db->from($table_name);
    $this->db->join('pp_companies', 'pp_employers.company_ID = pp_companies.ID', 'left');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
    //exit;
}
public function get_all_active_employers($per_page, $page) {
    $Q = $this->db->query("CALL get_all_active_employers($page, $per_page)");
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->result();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->next_result();
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}   

public function get_all_active_top_employers($per_page, $page) {
    $Q = $this->db->query("CALL get_all_active_top_employers($page, $per_page)");
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->result();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->next_result();
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}


public function get_company_details_by_slug($slug) {
    $Q = $this->db->query('CALL get_company_by_slug("'.$slug.'")');
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->next_result();
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}
```

I know, i'll have to use the implode function in my controller and make the name attribute into an array, i.e = category1[], But I'm not quite familiar with how to apply it in correctly this case, as many attempts to do this have resulted in the controller not displaying anything in the page.

It would help me a great deal if i can get some help on sorting this out.

Basically, Once if the Multiple values gets inserted into the database, I'll have a search and filter running.

EDIT 1 : Added Controller and Models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out , while initializing your array in the public function validation in the controller section for your array attribute

Should implicitly specify `'[]'` in set_rules

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('category1', 'Category1', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
```

to

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('category1[]', 'Category1', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
```

then it started accepting my query as an array with no issues, and as for the multiple selected items into the DB

Used this code , pretty self explanatory.

```
$arrcategory1 = $this->input->post('category1');
    foreach($arrcategory1 as $val1)
    {
        $categoryarr1 = $categoryarr1 . $val1. ",";
    }
    $categoryarr1 = substr(trim($categoryarr1), 0, -1);
```

and thats pretty much it, the field in category1 now shows Engineering,Management,Law as CSV

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="input-group <?php echo (form_error('category1'))?'has-error':'';?>">
<label class="input-group-addon">Category </label>
<select name="category1[]" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Engineering" <?php echo (set_value('category1')=='Engineering')?'selected':''; ?>>Engineering</option>
  <option value="Management" <?php echo (set_value('category1')=='Management')?'selected':''; ?>>Management</option>
  <option value="Law" <?php echo (set_value('category1')=='Law')?'selected':''; ?>>Law</option>
</select>
```

Comment: tried doing what you told @sintakonte, added [] at the end of the name attribute, When i submit the form, The page just reloads itself, and to double check i go to the database and find the values not being inserted, but without the [] , a single value gets  inserted.

Comment: show me you controller and model code pls - with the brackets you get an array back now - so you've to handle it

Comment: Added the Controller and the Model in the edit., Yes the array handling part seems to be tricky. 
Does the Model play a part here? without any model modifications i was able to add just a single value into the DB like i said earlier.

Comment: I think you've to change your DB - because category1 is a field of pp_companies which is simply wrong because you need to add a m:n table (many-to-many relation) because you allow multiple assignments

Comment: So basically to add multiple values in a field under pp_companies table, you've to have a  m:n table which contains category1, category2.... etc ?

Comment: no you should make a table categories (with id, name , ...) here are the values Engineering, Management, Law, etc. and a table categories_pp_companies (category_id, pp_company_id)

Comment: thank you so much for your efforts on trying to help me out on this Issue. Means a great deal. But i have managed to figure out went wrong when i initialed an array in my view, will post it as the answer.